# My Log in app doesn't working(nodejs)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

When I enter my login and password, the application freeze and the browser is loading.I enter my login and password in ejs file.
Can someone tell me why code after sql deoesn't working?
My js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connect = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "artbook"
});

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('./index');
});
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.login + req.body.password);
    connect.connect(function(err){
        connect.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("mysql error",err);
        });
        var sql = 'SELECT imie FROM konta WHERE imie = "'+req.body.login+'" AND nazwisko = "'+req.body.password+'";'
        connect.query(sql, function (rows, err){
            connect.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log("query error",err);
            });
            for(var i in rows) {
                if(req.body.login === rows[i].imie && req.body.password === rows[i].nazwisko){
                    console.log('done');
                    res.render('./login')
                } 
            }
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Port serwera: 3000');
```

Comment: Your `app.post("/"` handler might not return anything to the client.

Comment: but why?console.log(req.body.login + req.body.password); i get my data from form in console

Comment: Does it log "done"?

Comment: Your SQL query is alright. I would say try logging in rows in the console. You might be getting an empty response.

Comment: @JonasW. nope :/

Comment: @AshrafulAlam Yup, i get undefined when i add to comment my if statement and console.log(rows[i].imie);

Comment: But why i get 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function **parameters** in connect.query() are in **wrong order**. First parameter is error, second one is the results, third (optional) is fields.
It should have been-

```
connect.query(sql, function(error, rows){
    if (error) throw error; // do your thing with error
    //results
    console.log(rows); 
})
```

Follow the documentation [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections)

Also, from your API, you have to send an error response if there is an error and handle error response on client side (browser).

Comment: When i log rows as you showed, i get undefined in console

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL query directly to your DB server if it returns the result?

Comment: Also, what do you get if you log the error on console. 
`if (error) console.log('error:', error)`

Comment: nvmd sorry it was problem with phpmyadmin, it's logging my rows but only rows[i].imie but not rows[i].nazwisko, why?

Comment: It's because of you have queried for imie field only. Change your SQL query to include nazwisko.

SELECT imie, nazwisko FROM konta WHERE...

Comment: oh my god how could i not see this, thank u very much and sorry for this stupid sql mistake. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connect = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "artbook"
});

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('./index');
});
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.login + req.body.password);
    connect.connect(function(err){
        connect.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("mysql error",err);
        });
        var sql = 'SELECT imie FROM konta WHERE imie = "'+req.body.login+'" AND nazwisko = "'+req.body.password+'";'
        connect.query(sql, function (err, rows){
            connect.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log("query error",err);
            });
            for(var i in rows) {
                if(req.body.login === rows[i].imie && req.body.password === rows[i].nazwisko){
                    console.log('done');
                    res.render('./login')
                } 
                console.log(rows[i].imie + rows[i].nazwisko);
            }
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Port serwera: 3000');`enter code here`
```

Comment: #Ashraful Alam look ad this, it's return Konradundefined (Konrad its correct but why undefined)